# Fine control of car following behaviour with AnyLogic RoadTraffic library

Tags: anylogic

I am working on a project to model vehicle traffic at signalized intersections.  I am interested in using the RoadTraffic library to help greatly speed up road network and intersection setup.

One thing I would like to control that I can't seem to find access to is the desired distance between vehicles.  I want to modify this to simulate different driving situations (i.e. - in bad weather we want to keep more distance between vehicles).  Is this possible with the RoadTraffic library?  Is there a way to customize the car following behaviour of the cars?  Also, does anyone know what car following model is being used (Gipps, IDM, custom)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will take my chances to answer this, because it would surprise me if someone says something different... 
But unfortunately, the traffic road library is not very flexible and the algorithm behind is not documented anywhere. You cannot decide for a car to change lane, you cannot define if a car is in the range of attention or not.

The only way you can do what you want is by setting up the speed of cars depending on how close other cars are in front or around it... but the functions that should work for you such as getCarInFront(), won't work because you cannot define the meaning of a car being in front or not depending on the distance and speed. So you have to do it "manually" by changing speed. You can do this through an event or using stop lines... but it's not straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I was thinking this was the case